# Get a TextArea to look the same across browsers?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I haven't find a satisfactory answer to this question, so here I go,

This is how my **textarea** looks on **Chrome**:

[image]
This is how the same page looks on **FireFox**:

[image]

Here's the HTML for this textarea:

```
<textarea class="t-field" cols="58" id="message" name="message" rows="6"></textarea>
```

So, what I would like to know is... 
**What's the CSS *trick* to get textareas to behave and look the same across browsers?**

Thanks in advance for your answers,
Kind Regards!

Comment: Can you not just give the textarea a width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `cols` and `rows` properties, try using CSS `width` and `height` properties

Comment: Great! thank you! this happens for overusing Ruby on Rails view Helpers. Never thought it was so easy!

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, you should use `width` and `height` to fix the size of the area. Rows and columns will vary depending on the size of the font being used by the browser, and may be open to other variations in interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cols` or `rows` just use css `width` and `height`. like this for example

```
textarea {
            width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 4px;
            background-color: #f8f8f8;
            font-size: 16px;
            resize: none;
          }
```

And save and run on both browsers.